# Trigger __construct function from another class

Tags: php, mysql, class, mysqli

I've created a class which is named connect, it includes a construct function for my database:

**construct.php**

```
<?php
    include('includes/constants.php');

    class connect {
        public $db;
        function __construct() {
            $this->db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die();
        }
    }   
?>
```

I'm trying to reach this class & function from within another class:

**mysql.php**

```
<?php
    include_once('construct.php');
    $connect = new connect();

    class mysql {
        function verifyLogInData($email, $password) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";

            if($stmt = $connect->db->prepare($query)) {
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
                $stmt->execute();

                if($stmt->fetch()) {
                    $stmt->close();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

However, it seems like I can't trigger the $connect object. What would be the right way to do this or should I trigger this function with another method?

Line which is giving me the error:

```
if($stmt = $connect->db->prepare($query)) {
```

Thanks in advance.

**PS: Any advice on my code is very much appreciated :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand variable scope. In this case, you can pass the instance into the method:

```
function verifyLogInData($email, $password, $connect) {...}
```

Though it might be better to inject it into the mysql class via the constructor, or indeed to merge the two into a single class - i dont see a good reson to have two when they are so closely coupled